# Power BI Embedded - Are there any public ClientID, ClientSecret & TenantIds available for implementing App-Owns Scenario of 'ServicePrincipal'

Tags: powerbi

I want to test the client (App Owns Data - ServicePrincipal Scenario) for my own learning. I don't have my own report.

I was curious if i could find some publicly available ClientID, ClientSecret & TenantIds for testing my client code.

please help how can i do this for my own learning?

i know there are Microsoft Sample codes available on following path for the API learning but all of them start from embed-token. I want to test through ClientID, ClientSecret & TenantIds

Microsft Samples:
https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there are no public ClientID, ClientSecret & TenantIds for testing. we can use tokens from https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#